# Layering sea map over Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

Im trying to layer data from Kartverket (Norwegian Mapping Authority) over my Mapbox map, but currently the only thing im getting returned is a transparent image. Im wondering if there are anyone else that have done anything similar that could help me figure out what could be wrong with the request.

```
map.on('load', function() {
map.addSource('wms-test', {
    'type': 'raster',
    'tiles': [
        'https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.dybdedata2?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Dybdekontur&styles=default&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=53.1,-13.6,85.94,42.8&width=256&height=256'
    ],
    'tileSize': 256
});

map.addLayer({
    'id': 'wms-layer',
    'type': 'raster',
    'source': 'wms-test',
    'paint': {}
});
```

});

Link to the getCapabilities for the wms:
https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.dybdedata2?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

I tried changing the CRS to multiple other values.
I tried rearranging the coordinates for bbox.
I tried different layers from the getCapabilities file, but none seem to work.